# Content governance mechanism

Tags: theory

I am studying for [an exam](http://www.un.org/Depts/OHRM/examin/p2websam.shtml) and there is a sample question like :

> You are the Manager of the UN web
>   site, which comprises of a number of
>   sub-sites, in the six official
>   languages, with information prepared
>   and produced by different Departments.
>   You have been asked by senior
>   Management to devise and establish a
>   clear, coherent, workable and
>   acceptable governance mechanism for
>   the entire site which will take into
>   account the different needs of the
>   content-providing Departments which
>   maintaining a degree of centralization
>   so that institutional branding is not
>   compromised. Prepare an outline for
>   this governance mechanism setting out
>   responsibilities of content-providers,
>   the technical group and the management
>   group

I just stuck at content governance management. I searched the web but not found much. Any hint, idea, document or resource will be a lifesaver for me.

Thanks your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should attack this from 2 sides, for governance you could look at models used in open source projects ( http://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+governance ) and for content management entitlements look for user roles ( http://www.google.com/search?q=content+management+user+roles ).